# Swift UNUsernotification applicationIconBadgeNumber displays always one

Tags: ios, swift, unusernotificationcenter

I've set the user notification. They got deliver well but the badge on the app icon is always one.
Here's my code:

```
let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
let options: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound];

center.requestAuthorization(options: options) {
        (granted, error) in
        if !granted {
            // ask for permission
  }
}
```

When the use click the button i schedule the notif:

```
 @IBAction func saveBtnPressed(sender: UIButton) {
    scheduleNotif()
}
```

Here's the scheduleNotif function

```
 func scheduleNotif() {
    let dateformatter = DateFormatter()
    dateformatter.dateStyle = DateFormatter.Style.medium
    dateformatter.timeStyle = DateFormatter.Style.short
    let dateFromString = dateformatter.date(from: selectDateTextField.text!)
    let fireDateOfNotification: Date = dateFromString!

    //Notif are enabled
    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = notifTitleTextField.text!
    content.body = notifNoteTextView.text
    content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()
    content.badge = UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber + 1 as NSNumber

    var trigger: UNCalendarNotificationTrigger
    var triggerDate = DateComponents()
    trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: triggerDate, repeats: false)
    let titleNospace = notifTitleTextField.text?.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "")
    var identifier = titleNospace
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: identifier, content: content, trigger: trigger)
    self.center.add(request, withCompletionHandler: { (error) in
        if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    })
}
```

Any idea why the badge will always display one and never increment as the notifications are delivered?

Thank you

Comment: It's just a label and not anything else. Apple does not provided a badge auto increments for local notifications.

Comment: @Mannopson so basically there is no way to increment that label as the notifications got delivered?

Comment: However you can provide a correct value and set them as a badge. For example: `content.badge = deliveredNotifications.count` or something like that ( shows only missed notifications count )

Comment: It shows only provided value, in your case it's one (1).

Comment: it should not add one to UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber? which actually is correct... i mean if i print it from the delegate (willPresent Notification) the value it's correct

Comment: There is nothing wrong.

Comment: seems like is not... but it always stays at 1 (one)... i don't get it...

Comment: Probably is because UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber is zero until the notification is delivered. So if i schedule the second notif before the first one is delivered it will still use zero (0) plus one... heck!

Comment: It's fact. As I said above, you can't implement such as effect while you're scheduling a new notification.

Comment: so i have to find a workaround.... with delivered notification it's odd... if app is in foreground... it wont trigger...

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to increment `applicationIconBadgeNumber`. So replace

```
content.badge = UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber + 1 as NSNumber
```

By:

```
UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber += 1
content.badge = UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber as NSNumber
```

Comment: if you do so it will increment the badge as soon as it scheduled... and not when it's delivered